Unable to play downloaded audio files from cloud storage
I've uploaded audio, image, and video files to Google Cloud Storage (GCS). While I can successfully download and view images and videos on my device, I'm encountering issues with playing audio files.
The audio files are stored with an MP3 file type. I've found that I can work around this problem by changing the file extension to webm for audio files. However, this solution is not ideal as it requires the browser to open every time I want to replay the audio, which disrupts the user experience.
CODE:
const storage = getStorage();
                    let file = post.fileUrl;
                    getDownloadURL(ref(storage, file))
                        .then((url) => {
                            const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                            xhr.responseType = 'blob';
                            xhr.onload = (event) => {
                                const blob = xhr.response;
                                //create a file from the returned blob
                                var file = new File(
                                    [blob],
                                    'file'
                                    ,
                                    {
                                        type: blob.type,
                                    },
                                );
                                //create anchor tag
                                var link = document.createElement('a');
                                //set the download attribute of the a tag to the name stored in the file
                                link.download = file.name;
                                //generate a temp url to host the file for download
                                link.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
                                link.click();
                            };

                            
                            xhr.open('GET', url);
                            xhr.send();
                        })
                        .catch((err) => {
                            console.log(err);})

I tried setting the file to mp3 since for audios it would download a xml file instead.
var file = new File(
                                    [blob],
                                    `${dataHandle}_GoodbyeApp
                                    ${
                                        post.fileType === 'audio'
                                            ? '.mp3'
                                            : ''
                                    }`,
                                    {
                                        type: blob.type,
                                    },
                                );

And now it always downloads an mp3 file which doesnt play.
Any ideas how I can use MP3?

please correct me if i get you wrong - you want to play audio file from its firebase storage url inside your react project ? and currently you are require to change the extension to webm  type . then please share to code you are using to upload the files to firebase storage .

@Rainysidewalks I want to download an audio that is hosted on cloud storage from my react project. But when I download it it doesnt play unless I use "webm" file type and it opens the audio in a browser. I can play the audio fine on the website itself, but the problem arises when I try to download it.

When downloading the MP3 file from GCS, ensure the server responds with the correct "Content-Type" header set to "audio/mpeg". This informs the browser that the downloaded data is indeed an MP3 audio file.

In the network tab, the header displays "Content-Type: webm" for downloaded audio, "image/jpeg" for images, and "video/quicktime" for videos. Thanks @chanpols now I see what to fix

Posting my comment as an answer:

When downloading the MP3 file from GCS, ensure the server responds with the correct "Content-Type" header set to "audio/mpeg". This informs the browser that the downloaded data is indeed an MP3 audio file.

